# Zooming in CorePlot on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, core-plot

I am using a `CPTScatterPlot` to plot some data in my Mac OS X app, and want to offer the ability to zoom in and out.

I can see that the iPhone version has the `allowPinchScaling` setting, but there doesn't seem to be a Mac equivalent.  Before I manually implement anything, I thought I'd check to see if perhaps this was already supported out-of-the-box.

Any pointers or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinch and scroll gestures are also available on the Mac. I don't think this feature has been included in any release yet, so you'll need to get the latest source from [GitHub](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot).

Comment: Ahh... I see that is in the 2.0 branch (I am using 1.5.1 from CocoaPods).  Just curious how stable the 2.0 branch is?  Do you reckon it is robust enough yet?  Thanks.

Comment: The 2.0 branch was merged into master right after the 1.5.1 release. Some people keep up with the latest code on master and I haven't heard any major issues.